# Eigenvalues of $A$ with $A^3 = A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I just got a quick practice question here that I think should be simple but I can't find a definitive answer.

> Let $A$ be a square matrix such that $A^3 = A$. What can you say about the eigenvalues of $A$?

It is multiple choice and all of the answers are combinations of $-1$, $1$, and $0$. I'm pretty sure $0$ and $1$ are possible but I'm not sure how to prove any of them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Write $A^3 - A = A(A^2 - I) = A(A+I)(A-I) = 0$.

Comment: Let $v$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $c$. Then $cv=Av=(A^3)v=(c^3)v$. So what can you say about $c$?

Comment: Oh ok, thanks to both of you for the help. It makes it pretty straight forward.

Comment: In general, the eigenvalues are roots of the minimal polynomial for $A$. If $A^3=A$, what do we know about the minimal polynomial for $A$?

Comment: Chance, if you can solve the problem now, write up an answer and post it. Then after a while you can accept your answer. This is encouraged on this website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimal polynomial of matrix $A$ satisfying $A^3=A$ is given by $x^3-x=0$,so the possible eigenvalues will be $0,1,-1$, depending on the given matrix now, we can select it from MCQ.

Comment: It's not necessarily the minimal polynomial; what you can say is that the minimal polynomial is a factor of $x^3-x$. However, the conclusion about the possible eigenvalues is correct; one can't say more because it's not possible to say what the minimal polynomial or the characteristic polynomial are.